# Custom events in Access database

Tags: class, ms-access, events, vba

I tried this in an Access newgroup, and got over a hundred views, but not a single response, so I hope it fares better here.

I'm trying to get a grip on custom events in VBA. I've scoured endless sources on the net, studied my manuals, experimented with everything I can think of, and success is still somewhat tenuous.

Exactly what I hope to accomplish is not all that complicated, and seems like it should be ideal for custom event routines. I have main forms with comboboxes and listboxes fed from tables or queries. The user can open various dialog boxes and do things to modify the tables. When that activity is done, I would like to requery the box(es) affected by any such activity. The way I have done it in the past was to set a global 'SourceHasChanged' Boolean variable and check its status upon returning from the dialog. It works, but is a bit unwieldy, so I decided to try replacing this with custom events.

Hours of studying and endless dead-end tries and repeats have finally produced the following bits of code. They do nothing spectacular. There is a table called T. The dialog form adds records on each click of the Add button. The main form has another button that deletes all but the first record in the table. Each set of code is supposed to fire an event indicating that the listbox is to be requeried. The code in the main form does okay, but the code in the dialog refuses to activate the StalaSeZmena event. Obviously (I think, anyway), that's because the dialog from creates a new instance of the class module. But I have to have a WithEvents variable in the dialog form. If I don't, I would have to make a reference to the WithEvents variable in the main form. Requiring forms to know that much about each other is exactly back-asswards from what I thought the custom event route was going to accomplish. It would be easier and less confusing to just stay with a global status variable.

Class Module [Zmena]

```
Public WithEvents Udalost As HlaseniZmeny
Private Sub Udalost_StalaSeZmena()
Form_Mane.lstS.Requery
Debug.Print "Requery via class module"
End Sub
```

Class Module [HlaseniZmeny]

```
Public Event StalaSeZmena()
Public Sub OhlasitZmenu()
RaiseEvent StalaSeZmena
End Sub
```

Regular Module

```
Public chg As Zmena
```

Form Code [Mane]

```
Private WithEvents chgMane As HlaseniZmeny
Private Sub cmdCallDialog_Click()
DoCmd.OpenForm "Dia", acNormal, , , , acDialog
End Sub

Private Sub cmdShrinkT_Click()
CurrentDb.Execute "Delete * From T Where Pole1 <> 'A'"
chgMane.OhlasitZmenu
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Me.Label1.Caption = Me.SpinButton1.Value
Set chg = New Zmena
Set chgMane = New HlaseniZmeny
Set chg.Udalost = chgMane
End Sub

Private Sub chgMane_StalaSeZmena()
lstS.Requery
Debug.Print "Requery from event on main"
End Sub
```

Form Code [Dia]

```
Private WithEvents chgDia As HlaseniZmeny
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
CurrentDb.Execute "Insert Into T (Pole1) Values(chr(asc('" & DMax("Pole1", "T", "Pole1") & "')+1))"
Set chgDia = New HlaseniZmeny
Set chg.Udalost = chgDia
chgDia.OhlasitZmenu
Set chgDia = Nothing
End Sub
```

It's functional, but feels awkward, clunky and not at all intuitive, like scratching my left ear with my right foot. The class module has a reference to the main form, which violates the principle of encapsulation, but I found no way to make the dialog form activate the event routine in the main form. I have to have a global variable to link the two WithEvents variables to, or nothing works, but this also violates encapsulation.

Is this really how these constructs are supposed to operate, or have I accidentally stumbled onto a Mad-Max version that happens to work, but isn't the proper way to build such procedures?

Comment: Isn't your problem that you use a _dialogue_ form? Dialogue mode stops everything else outside the form. Couldn't you try just to make it a modal non-dialogue form?

Comment: A good source is this from _John Colby_: [John's Access Blog](https://jwcolby.blogspot.dk/?view=sidebar)

Comment: I'm not sure what my problem is, hence the post. All I've gotten so far is that it doesn't work. You're right, that a dialog form halts other user activity. Does it also stop event code that is not in the form? Event code in the form works fine. Would making it non-modal fix that? I can try it, but then I'd open up another can of worm, of the user possibly doing something outside of the dialog form. I use dialog mode precisely to keep that from happening. I'll certainly take a look at John's site. I thought I knew most of the sites run by Access heavyweights, but this is a new one for me. Thx.

Comment: If the non-dialogue mode should work, you could try simulate dialogue mode as described here: [Modern/Metro style message box and input box for Microsoft Access 2013](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/17684/Modern-Metro-style-message-box-and-input-box-for-Microsoft-Access-2013.html)

Comment: Hm, that's an interesting technique, but for what I'm trying to get done here, is quite complicated. My goal with the custom event was to make my life simpler. This would add a great deal of complexity - I'd be better off just keeping my global DataHasChanged boolean variable and not using events at all. But that looks like it could be useful in other situations. I'll  keep it in mind.

Comment: I would caution against sinking custom events in an Access Form. You can get into tricky situations where order of class shutdown is critical. It is easy to crash Access in these situations. Looking at your code, I would say events are unnecessary. Perhaps it is best to say you've gained some experience, learned, and then move on to something simpler.

Comment: Well, so far all I've learned is that I don't know how to do this, which is not where I was hoping to be. Even if I am completely off base in this situation, I'd like to get a better handle on events in general. I use the standard Access ones all the time, and think I know what I'm doing pretty well with those, but I'm always looking to improve my skills and learn new things. The boyz who wrote Access included custom events deliberately, so I assume there are cases where they are the appropriate tool for the job. I'd like to add them to my skill set, since I use Access almost daily.